# How do I perform this modify or insert line with sed correctly?

Tags: sed

I am running this on a test crontab file with these contents:

```
00 01 * * * foo --file example/example.xml --bla
00 02 * * * foo --file abc/abc.xml --bla
```

I am trying to replace the first line (if it exists) with something else, say 'bar', or inserting the bar line if it could not find it at all by running this:

```
sed -e '@\(.*file example/example.xml .*\)@bar@' -e t -e 's@^@bar@' file
```

I would expect the above to try to replace a matching example line with bar, and if it does not find it to insert a bar line. When I run it with the above, however, I get this output:

```
bar
bar00 02 * * * foo --file abc/abc.xml --bla
```

So it performed the substitution but somehow the `t` jump to end did not take place and it also inserted `bar` on the next line. What went wrong?

The command given by sat below seems to work but fails to append if I run it twice and I'm not sure why:

```
cat file
1 bin/appple #apple
2 bin/orange #orange
cat file | sed -e '\@.* #apple@{d}; $a 1 bin/apple #apple'
2 bin/orange #orange
1 bin/apple #apple
cat file | sed -e '\@.* #apple@{d}; $a 1 bin/apple #apple' | sed -e '\@.* #apple@{d}; $a 1 bin/apple #apple'
2 bin/orange #orange
```

The above behaved as I wanted the first two times, but the last command simply removes the line and doesn't append it back. Why would that be? (btw I changed # to \@ because I use # in there as you can imagine for a crontab comment)

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the typo (a missing `s`), the command:

```
sed -e 's@\(.*file example/example.xml .*\)@bar@' -e t -e 's@^@bar@' file
```

Is working as you requested; you are misunderstanding the scope of `t`, I think.  The test applies to each line of input in turn, not to the script as a whole.  So, the script says:

- If the line contains `file example/example.xml`, replace it with `bar`.
- If the substitute was done, skip to the end of the script (for the current input line).
- Replace the start of the line with `bar` (which happens to the second data line because it doesn't match `file example/example.xml`).

(I note in passing that the `\(` and `\)` are not needed when the replacement is `bar`, but that's probably just a remnant from a more complex replacement where you did use `\1`.)

OK; that's why your script behaves as it does.  How can we make it behave the way you want?  In part, the answer depends on whether the order of the lines in the output is critical.

1. If the order doesn't matter, then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956716/15168) by [sat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874178/sat) does the job.  If it finds the matching text line, it deletes it.  At the end of the file, it adds the new line.  Thus, regardless of whether the line was there or not, the output contains the new required output at the end of the file. (For a `crontab` file, this should be quite adequate.)
2. If the order does matter, you have a much harder job.  In this case, you can make use of the hold space to determine if the whether the pattern was found.  However, if you needed the hold space for something else, or you needed several patterns replaced or added, you couldn't readily adapt this to fix the problem (you'd have to be cleverer about it).

#### If the order matters

Don't use this if the order of the lines doesn't matter.

Example: file `sed.script` contains:

```
/.*file example\/example.xml.*/ {
h
s//bar/
}
$ {
p
x
s/./X/
t end
s/.*/bar/
q
:end
d
}
```

This script has two sets of operations.  The first set, when the line matches `file example/example.xml` is simple; it copies the line into the hold space (so the hold space is no longer empty), and then does the substitution operation.

The second set is far more complex; it operates at the end of the script.  First, it prints the current line.  If that line had been fixed by the first block (so the `file example/example.xml` appeared on the last line), it prints the modified form of the line.  Then it swaps the hold and pattern spaces. It does a trial substitution (`s/./X/`).  The `t` command jumps to the label `end` if a substitution was made, which means that the line was not empty, which means that the hold space was filled, so the pattern was replaced (at least) once before.  If the `t` doesn't jump, the match pattern was not seen, so the code replaces the current line with `bar` (the replacement text) and quits (which prints the final line and abandons the script).  The label `end` is followed by `d` which deletes the current line and 'moves to the next cycle' except there is no next cycle when the `$` match is in effect, so there's nothing left to print.

Example runs:

```
$ cat file
00 01 * * * foo --file example/example.xml --bla
00 02 * * * foo --file abc/abc.xml --bla
$ sed -f sed.script file
bar
00 02 * * * foo --file abc/abc.xml --bla
$ sed -f sed.script file | sed -f sed.script
bar
00 02 * * * foo --file abc/abc.xml --bla
bar
$ sed -f sed.script /dev/null
$
```

The first `sed` shows that the `example/example.xml` line is replaced in situ.  The second `sed` shows that when `example/example.xml` line is missing, `bar` is added at the end.  The last example (`/dev/null`) shows that you need at least one line of input for it to work properly; it won't bootstrap from an empty file.

*There is probably a simpler way to handle this.  I just haven't worked out what it is.*

#### If the order doesn't matter

This is basically the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956716/15168) by [sat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874178/sat) with the order of the operations reversed.  It works when the line to be deleted is the last line in the file:

```
sed -e '$a bar' -e '/.*file example\/example.xml.*/d' file
```

Comment: That second example is pretty involved, for some reason the simple command @sat gave is not working when iterated twice - as per the edit I made above for an example.

Comment: The variation by [sat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874178/sat) probably fails when the last line matches, because the `d` terminates the current cycle on the last line, and therefore skips the `a` operation (informed guess — not proven).  I know my version is convoluted; I would probably not use `sed` for this job because it is convoluted.  But I think it does work, which is a saving grace.

Comment: It does, and the sat version works if broken into two separate sed commands interleaved with pipe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed '\#file example/example.xml#{d}; $a bar' yourfile
```

Comment: What's the # for? and $a? What is this doing?

Comment: `#` is a pattern matching delimiter, `$` is a end of file and `a` is append.

Comment: I think you should explain what you're doing.  It works, but it isn't obvious how or why it works because you've rewritten the algorithm (it doesn't do exactly what is requested, but the result is equivalent) and you're using a moderately obscure part of `sed` with the `\#` notation.

Comment: As you pointed out it does behave as expected but when I run this twice it actually performs the delete but not the append for some reason

Comment: You can fix this by using `sed -e '$a bar' -e '/.*file example\/example.xml.*/d'` (simply reversing the append and delete operations).